# Identificar uma parte especifica da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

É possível eu identificar uma parte específica da tela com Jquery os javascript? Por exemplo ao passar pela altura y ele executar para mim uma função? 
Imagino algo assim:

```
var minha_altura = $(window).height();
var altura       = 400;
if(minha_altura > 400) 
{
   //faz algo
}
```

Está correto o conceito e de fato isso funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um evento no window para detectar o movimento do mouse e com isso o pageX/Y dele.

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if(event.pageY > 400) {
    //{...}
  } else {
    //{...}
  }
});
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<p> PageY:'+e.pageY+'</p><p> PageX:'+e.pageX+'</p>';
});
```

Comment: muito obrigado pelo feedback, eu conseguiria fazer isto com o scroll da página tb?

Comment: @MarcosHenrique Claso que sim, desta forma é possível. `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
console.log(window.scrollY);
});`

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, foi de grande valia